# speed up for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Update: the original problem was solved, now only the `georoute` loop is left to be dealt.

I am a real beginner in R, so sorry if this question seems simple. I created this `for loop` simply wanted to distinguish two type of data. There is an `engine_type` column in my data of five levels ("DA" "DM" "EA" "PA" PM"), and I just wanted two levels ("EA" and those not). Here is my code.

```
for(i in which(totd$engine_type == "EA")){
  totd[i,16]= "EA"
}
for(i in which(totd$engine_type != "EA")){
  totd[i,16]= "Non_EA"
}
```

This works fine but since my dataset is huge (781225 rows) so it's taking forever to do this. I felt like this should be able to be accomplished with functions to speed up the process but I just can't find a way. I also read about vectorization and other posts but honestly I have no idea how to apply them here. Any tips will be hugely appreciated!!

**ps. if there is a way to speed up this loop, would that also be applicable to my georoute code in the following as well? (I need to cut it off in a lot of times because of the quota limit)

`georoute` requires the package of TaRifxgeo, and you would need to obtain a free key from bing map to get any results.. from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff428642.aspx) **

```
for(i in 250000:281224){
  DT1[i,]=tryCatch(t(as.matrix(unlist(georoute( 
c(as.character(LL$latlon[i]), as.character(LL$latlon_end[i])), verbose=TRUE, 
       returntype=c("time", "distance"))),
       nrow = 1, ncol = 2)),
       error=function(a) {"."} )
}
```

So my data have the latitude and longitude of an origin and the destination, where it appears as the following.

```
           latlon          latlon_end
```

1 52.481466 13.317647| 52.518811 13.413034
2 52.518811 13.413034| 52.504182 13.318051
3 52.504182 13.318051| 52.502236 13.305396
4 52.502236 13.305396| 52.548096 13.355104
5 52.548096 13.355104| 52.569865 13.410967
6 52.569865 13.410967|  52.54505 13.419071

what georoute takes is these two data and then generates, for each pair, a list of `time` and `distance`, that's the reason for the unlisting and t and etc. I tried applying lapply/sapply but it just won't work if I input all the data all in once. Any idea?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think `ifelse` could be faster. If the new column you're creating is called `newLevels`, for example, you could fill it using `totd$newLevels <- ifelse(totd$engine_type == "EA", "EA", "Non_EA")` Then you can avoid having to write a loop.

Comment: dammit it worked in 5 seconds, I felt like a fool posting this question now.. Thank you so much!! Do you have any idea about speeding up the georoute code?

Comment: Not sure without seeing the data - would you be able to edit your question to post a sample of the data, and what you'd expect to see as the output? Also, are you using a particular library for the georoute function? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Yes it is.. I added the data and explained the usage of the packages and stuff. It's kinda complicated in terms of replicating

Answer (score 1):

A sample data frame might be created like so:

```
totd <- data.frame(a=rnorm(20), engine_type=sample(c("DA","DM","EA","PA","PM"),20,replace=TRUE))
```

You can get a vector of booleans indicating whether or not the row has engine type 'EA':

```
totd$engine_type == 'EA'
```

With that, you can subset your original data frame:

```
totd[ totd$engine_type == 'EA', ]
```

...and compute statistics for subsets, for example on numeric field 'a':

```
summary(totd[ totd$engine_type == 'EA', 'a'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In R you generally don't need to process row by row, formualae are vectorised and where you want to apply a function to several elements of a list of vector you should use lapply or sapply, etc

I can't tell if the below will work without seeing your data but try

```
 DT1[250000:281224,]<-tryCatch(t(as.matrix(unlist(georoute( 
   as.character(LL$latlon_end[250000:281224])), verbose=TRUE, 
   returntype=c("time", "distance"))),
   nrow = 1, ncol = 2)),
   error=function(a) {"."} )
```

Comment: I struggled a bit trying to post the data nice and neat here. Your codes were my first try but it wouldn't work if I input all of them in once.. and I don't really know why.
and I edited a bit my old codes because I just realized the second input was missed previously. Hope this is more presentable now!